# Segundo maior valor de uma lista python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quero que seja encontrado o segundo maior valor de uma lista sem excluir nenhum elemento nela; tentei usar o comando min e max, porém isso só funciona com maior e menor. No caso quero que retorne o número 5.

`lista = [4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Não é só fazer `print(sorted(lista)[-2])`?

Answer (score 4):

Apresento abaixo algumas alternativas a solução com `sorted` ([veja resposta do Paulo Marques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/483407/100)).

Python possui a função `nlargest` que retorna os `n` maiores elementos de uma lista usando um `heap` de tamanho `n`. Conforme [documentação do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html), para números de `n` pequenos (como 2) essa função é bastante eficiente.

```
import heapq
print(heapq.nlargest(2, lista)[-1])
```

Do ponto de vista teórico essa solução possui complexidade `O(n*log(2))` e consumo de memória `O(2)`. A solução com `sorted` tem complexidade `O(n*log(n))` e consumo de memória `O(n)`

Uma outra alternativa é fazer uma cópia da lista, remover o máximo e então obter o máximo da lista resultante (assim a lista original não é modificada):

```
copia_lista = lista.clone()
copia_lista.remove(max(copia_lista))
print(max(copia_lista))
```

Essa solução é `O(n)` em espaço e tempo.

Finalmente você também pode percorrer a lista guardando os dois maiores números conforme [essa pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16225677/664577). Eis a minha variação da resposta aceita no SOen:

```
def second_largest(numbers):
    if len(numbers) < 2:
        return None
    m1 = m2 = float('-inf')
    for x in numbers:
        if x > m2:
            if x >= m1:
                m1, m2 = x, m1            
            else:
                m2 = x
    return m2

print(second_largest(lista))
```

Essa solução é `O(n)` em tempo e `O(2)` em espaço.

OBS: O algoritmo teoricamente mais rápido não necessariamente será o mais rápido na prática. A *performance* de cada algoritmo também pode ser bastante sensível ao tamanho e conteúdo da lista original.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução simpes seria:

1. Ordena a lista em ordem decrescente
2. Pega o segundo elemento

```
>>> lista = [1, 3, 2, 10, 7]

>>> print(sorted(lista, reverse=True)[1])
7
```

Entretanto, caso vc tenha números repetidos na lista, o ideal é pegar o `set` da mesma:

```
>>> lista = [1, 3, 2, 10, 7, 10, 7, 3 ,2]

>>> print(sorted(lista, reverse=True)[1])  # Não funciona, pois a lista ordenada é [10, 10, 7, 7, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]
10

>>> print(sorted(set(lista), reverse=True)[1])  # Agora sim, o set não aceita duplicados, sendo assim a lista é ordenada é [10, 7, 3, 2, 1]
7
```

Espero que ajude